# Compiling zsh from source has started spewing errors and warnings

Tags: bash, scripts, python, make, configure

I have a simple script written in bash to pull the latest changes in zsh's official github's repo and build it.

I also have another script (still bash) which calls this and other scripts.

Plus, I have ANOTHER (this time written in python) which calls the second script.

I noticed that since yesterday it didn't give me this kinds of errors,
but now at a middle point I get this:

```
(eval):print:4: write error: broken pipe
(eval):4: write error: inappropriate ioctl for device
```

repeated in the same order something like 10 times.

This only happens when it gets called by the second script called from the python script.

If I directly call it, or the second script does but isn't itself called from the python script.

Also, I'd like to specify that I am no master at shell scripts and I can't change stuff in the internal tools needed to compile zsh.

This is the zsh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if  [[ $EUID > 0 ]] ; then
    echo "You need to be root for this script."
    exit
fi  

cd ~/Desktop/zsh

git pull origin master

./configure --prefix=/usr \
            --mandir=/usr/share/man \
            --bindir=/bin \
            --infodir=/usr/share/info \
            --enable-maildir-support \
            --enable-etcdir=/etc/zsh \
            --enable-function-subdirs \
            --enable-site-fndir=/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions \
            --enable-fndir=/usr/share/zsh/functions \
            --with-tcsetpgrp \
            --with-term-lib="ncursesw" \
            --enable-cap \
            --enable-pcre \
            --enable-readnullcmd=pager \
            --enable-custom-patchlevel=Debian \
            LDFLAGS="-Wl,--as-needed -g"

make

make check

sudo make install

sudo make install.info
```

This is the second one:

```
#!/bin/bash

if  [[ $EUID > 0 ]] ; then
    echo "You need to be root for this script."
    exit
fi 

echo "Building zsh."

build-zsh

clear

echo "Done building zsh, moving on to ssh."

build-ssh

clear 

echo "Done building ssh, moving on to nmap."

build-nmap

clear

echo "Done building nmap."

echo "End of the script."
```

And this is the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

if os.geteuid() != 0:
    exit("You need root privileges to run this script.")

comando = "apt-fix -y && apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y full-upgrade  && apt-get -y dist-upgrade && \
apt-file update && apt -y autoremove --purge && apt -y clean"

spegnere = input ("Do you wish to turn shutdown after the process is completed? (y/n) ")

if spegnere.lower() == "y":
    comando+= " && poweroff"
    print("The pc will shutdown after the process is ended.")

os.system("build-all") # Second script
os.system(comando)
```